# Could not find matching version

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to install [geograpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geograpy) on my mac but gives me following error.

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement geography (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for geography

Comment: Shouldn't it be `geograpy` and not `geography`. Note the `h`.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: If my answer is helpful below, please mark as correct, +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your package name is incorrect. It should be `geograpy` and not `geography`. Remove the `h`.